# Objectbox Sync with Fly.io

Tags: docker, objectbox, flutter-objectbox, fly

I would like apply objectbox sync to `fly.io`. In testing in local, it is fine with the docker command. But in deploying to `fly.io`, I have no opinion with how to work `-model` command in `fly.io`.

```
docker run --rm -it \
    --volume "$(pwd):/data" \
    --publish 127.0.0.1:9999:9999 \
    --publish 127.0.0.1:9980:9980 \
    --user $UID \
    objectboxio/sync:sync-server-2022-10-21 \
    --model /data/objectbox-model.json \
    --unsecured-no-authentication \
    --admin-bind 0.0.0.0:9980
```

Comment: Which Docker image using not clear, what is the error you are getting not mentioned here.  Is it just fear of failure?

Comment: @PavanDevarakonda docker image is provided by objectbox for synchroniation testing.My problem is  , I can successfully run in local with this command with docker. But in uploading to fly.io , I don't know where to add this --model /data/objectbox-model.json for database schema.

Comment: The model file is stored in the current directory, which is mounted as a volume under /data inside the Docker container. Volumes are also available for fly.io, see the last section: https://fly.io/docs/languages-and-frameworks/dockerfile/#taking-it-further (or https://fly.io/docs/reference/volumes/ directly). You should be able to put the model file there.

Comment: @Uwe-ObjectBox , I have added volume to fly.io and [mounts]
    source="myapp_data"
    destination="/data" in fly.toml. but it is not working yet. Is there anything I need to do ? I have also copied objectbox-model.json to root directory.

Comment: Sorry, no. I have not used fly.io myself. Do they have a support forum, maybe you can ask there on how to set up volumes?

Comment: @Uwe-ObjectBox is there any deployment guide to follow in hosting sync server. I am quite stuck with it. Is there any support form objectbox team for it?

Comment: No deployment guide besides https://sync.objectbox.io/objectbox-sync-server at this point. We offer support if you are a Sync customer: https://objectbox.io/sync/